# Qt QTabWidget : Tab too small for Text inside it

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently using this style-sheet for Qtabwidget

```
QTabBar::tab
{
  background: transparent;
 margin : 30px; 
 border-style: solid;
 border-width:2px;
 border-bottom-width : 0px;
 border-color: rgb(96,96,96);
 font: 14pt "Impact";
 top : 5px;
}
```

However the font and size that I am using is to small for the Tab . It seems to me that the tab has a huge size but the text seems to be chipped. Any idea why I have such a small text space in the tab ?

Comment: I have the same issue. The border seems to be generating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with your 30px margin. Try making this smaller and seeing if that helps.